# How can I decompile and/or view the mshtml.dll file?

Tags: vba, dll

So far I have tried ISpy and received "This file does not contain a managed assembly." I also tried PEBrowse but couldn't even open it without getting an error

Comment: IDAPro will do a wonderful job.

Answer (score 0):

mshtml.dll is the rendering core of Internet Explorer. It is written in native code, not .NET so therefore it cannot be decompiled as "managed assembly". It is "unmanaged" code.

If you are reverse engineering some module, you may treat the call to MSHTML a native call.

Comment: I'm trying to find out what the default interface is for the objects in the mshtml.dll library.  Is this possible?

Comment: If you are trying to bind to some functions, use a tool called IDA to export the names and functions.